# RequestAdapter and MultipartFormData

Tags: alamofire

Thank you for the nice work you put into this amazing library.

I have an issue with my request adapter but only with the MultipartFormData.

I want to be able to update the body of the request but when the request gets in the adapter, I'm getting a `nil` httpBody. I only get this behaviour on Multipart, not on classic POST requests.

I'm trying to sign the request with an oauth2 token (async), but the particularity of this API is that the token is sent in the body and not in the headers.

There's a body as the metrics in the response say `(Request Body Transfer Bytes) 231306`

I'm using Alamofire 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to multipart forms using `UploadRequest`s (and therefore `URLSessionUploadTasks`) which do not include the body data as part of the `URLRequest` for performance reasons. If you update your question with what you're trying to do to the body, perhaps I can provide an alternate solution. If nothing else, you could manually create multipart uploads by using `MultipartFormData.encode()` directly and adding the `Data` to a `URLRequest`, but that's not recommended for large uploads.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to update a multipart form body with extra data like that? Is this some sort of custom encoding? Otherwise I don't see how it could work while still letting the server parse the multipart form. More details are still needed.

Comment: For basic POST request I'm decoding the httpBody of the urlRequest, I append my token, re-encode my data and set it to my new urlRequest. Yet, I don't know how to handle this with the multipart form.

Comment: I suggest you consult your server documentation to see how that's supposed to work. Only thing I can think of is that you append your token as part of the body data. Or you need to encode your body data and then put that inside a JSON payload. And you don't need to decode and reencode, you can use a generic wrapper to get what you need there.